# Change display month on select box

Tags: magento2, phtml, date

I have a module and a select box for display month. In file download.phtml, I mentionn value month and I want display that are 01, 02, 03, ..., 12. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script

```
<?php
$getMonth = [];
foreach (range(1, 12) as $m) {
    $getMonth[] = date('m - F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($getMonth);
?>
```

It will show output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01 - January
    [1] => 02 - February
    [2] => 03 - March
    [3] => 04 - April
    [4] => 05 - May
    [5] => 06 - June
    [6] => 07 - July
    [7] => 08 - August
    [8] => 09 - September
    [9] => 10 - October
    [10] => 11 - November
    [11] => 12 - December
)
```

For select box

```
<?php
$getMonth = [];
echo "<select>";
foreach (range(1, 12) as $m) {
    $month = date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
    echo "<option>".$month."</option>";
    
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

**Output**

[image]

You can modify according to your requirement.

Comment: I want to display 01, 02, 03, not Jan, Feb, Mar....help me pls!

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: how can I display current month? sorry because I'm a newbie :(

Comment: $month = date('m');

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659389/php-get-the-current-month-of-a-date/20659745

Comment: Is it working or not ?

Comment: Sorry I'm reply late. It's working for me. Tks for your help!

Comment: And 1 more question. Use your code but now I want to get a before month? now is 07(July), I want to display 06(June)..how can I do that?